# How to receive notifications every time a media session is opened/changed/closed in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

How can I receive notifications in my app every time a media session is opened/changed/closed with the MediaSession API in Android and in other apps.

In the logcat, I can see how these events are fired but I don't have any idea of how can I listen for them inside my app:

```
... D/vol.MediaSessions: onPlaybackStateChanged com.spotify.music STATE_PLAYING PlaybackState {state=3, position=421...

... D/vol.MediaSessions: onPlaybackStateChanged com.google.android.youtube STATE_PLAYING PlaybackState ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you need register a callback using

> MediaControllerCompat

and override below method to capture state like play, pause, resume

> onPlaybackStateChanged

if you need more information to receiving updates on from the session please visit below link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.Callback